# Python Error: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a math quiz program for my Python class, but I keep getting an error with the `sum()` function. The error is:

```
'int' object is not iterable.
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
import math

def main():
  print('This is a simple math quiz that will test your addition skills.\n')
  print('\tGood Luck!\n\n')

  # Get two random integers
  num1 = random.randint(1, 1001)
  num2 = random.randint(1, 1001)

  print('What is the sum of ', num1, ' and ', num2, '?')

  student_answer = int(input('Enter your answer, then press Enter: '))

  answer = sum(num1, num2)

  if student_answer == answer:
    print('Congratulations! You got it right!')
  else:
    print('Sorry, your answer is not correct!')

  print(answer)

main()

def sum(number1, number2): 
    return number1 + number2
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Terrence\Desktop\Python Assignments\Chapter 6\Math Quiz.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Terrence\Desktop\Python Assignments\Chapter 6\Math Quiz.py", line 20, in main
    answer = sum(num1, num2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that, at the time you call `main`, you haven't yet defined `sum`.

So, why isn't this a `NameError`? Because there's already a builtin named [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), so you're calling *that*. And that function requires an iterable of values, not two separate values. (If you don't know what an iterable is: It's something you can loop over in a `for` loop, like a list.) So, it looks at your first argument—a random integer—and tries to use it as an iterable. And that's why you get that error.

If you move your definition up above the call to `main()`, your code will work. However, it will still be a source of confusion. This is one reason it's better to avoid giving your functions the same name as any of the builtins.

As a side note, the function you're defining already exists, as `operator.add`. The reason `add` and friends are tucked away in the `operator` module is that you usually don't need them. If you just want to add two numbers, `a + b` is always clearer than `sum(a, b)`. You only need it as a separate function when you need to pass that function around (e.g., to use as an argument to `map`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I thought it was a built in function, but my book made me think otherwise. My book also defined the function below the main function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2864319: What book are you using? It may be for a very old version of Python, before the builtin was added (2.3, which I think is more than a decade ago). Or it may just be a very bad book… Either way, you might want to find a better one, or get used to checking with the interpreter's built-in help or the web docs as you go through the book.

Comment: I am using Starting out with Python 2nd. Edition. The program in the book not only places the function definition below the main function, but it also defines the sum function.

Comment: @user2864319: Wow. [That book](http://www.amazon.com/Starting-Python-Edition-Gaddis-Series/dp/0132576376) is from 2011, and it's written for Python 3.x, so… this one must have just slipped through. Do they have an "errata" section on the publisher's website that might help you out with any similar errors later in the book?

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is already a builtin function!

Usage: `sum(list)`

```
>>> sum([1,5])
>>> 6
```

In your code:

```
answer = sum([num1, num2])
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why his own `sum` function is being ignored. Also, the builtin `sum` takes any iterable (and optionally a start value), so `sum(list)` is not a very good usage description.

Answer (score 0):

Place the sum function on the top of main function.

ex:

```
def sum(number1, number2): 
  ...

def main():
  ...
```

Then call the main function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a int can't be an iterator in sum build in function , you need to make it a list :

```
num1 = random.randint(1, 1001)
num2 = random.randint(1, 1001)
a = [num1, num2]

answer = sum(a)
```